# How to know how many persistent objects were deleted using Session.Delete(query);

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sql-delete

We are refactoring a project from plain MySQL queries to the usage of NHibernate.
In the MySQL connector there is the [ExecuteNonQuery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery) function that returns the rows affected. So

```
int RowsDeleted = ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM `table` WHERE ...");
```

would show me how many rows where effectively deleted.

How can I achieve the same with NHibernate? So far I can see it is not possible with `Session.Delete(query);`.

My current workaround is first loading all of the objects that are about to be deleted and delete them one-by-one, incrementing a counter on each delete. But that will cost performance I may assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind that nHibernate will create delete statements for each row and maybe additional statements for orphans and/or other relationships, you can use `session.Delete`.

For better performance I would recommend to do batch deletes (see example below).

## session.Delete

If you delete many objects with session.Delete, nHibernate makes sure that the integrity is preserved, it will load everything into the session if needed anyways. So there is no real reason to count your objects or have a method to retrieve the number of objects which have been deleted, because you would simply do a query before running the delete to determine the number of objects which will be affected...

The following statement will delete all entities of type post by id.
The select statement will query the database only for the Ids so it is actually very performant...

```
var idList = session.Query<Post>().Select(p => p.Id).ToList<int>();
session.Delete(string.Format("from Post where Id in ({0})", string.Join(",", idList.ToArray())));
```

The number of objects deleted will be equal to the number of Ids in the list...

This is actually the same (in terms of queries nHibernate will fire against your database) as if you would `query<T>` and loop over the result and delete all of them one by one...

## Batch delete

You can use `session.CreateSqlQuery` to run native SQL commands. It also allows you to have input and output parameters.

The following statement would simply delete everything from the table as you would expect

```
session.CreateSQLQuery(@"Delete from MyTableName");
```

To retrieve the number of rows delete, we'll use the normal TSQL `@@ROWCOUNT` variable and output it via select. To retrieve the selected row count, we have to add an output parameter to the created query via `AddScalar` and `UniqueResult` simple returns the integer:

```
var rowsAffected = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"
        Delete from MyTableName; 
        Select @@ROWCOUNT as NumberOfRows")
    .AddScalar("NumberOfRows", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
    .UniqueResult();
```

To pass input variables you can do this with `.SetParameter(<name>,<value>)`

```
var rowsAffected = session.CreateSQLQuery(@"
        DELETE from MyTableName where ColumnName = :val; 
        select @@ROWCOUNT NumberOfRows;")
     .AddScalar("NumberOfRows", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
     .SetParameter("val", 1)
     .UniqueResult();
```

I'm not so confortable with MySQL, the example I wrote is for MSSQL, I think in MySQL the `@@ROWCOUNT` equivalent would be `SELECT ROW_COUNT();`?

Comment: Thank you for your most useful answer. However, it makes the application database type depended, or the query should be written for each database type supported for NHibernate and check which dialect is used during runtime. I was hoping there would be a more elegant way. Nevertheless your answer is of value.

Comment: Actually no, there is no other way than this to do deletes in one go (apart from using the plain sql objects and ignoring nHibernate completly...). 
If you use normal session.Delete or also deleting multiple Entities, nHibernate will always retrieve the relationships and may delete orphans or cross table entries for you. This is cool, but it will always do it one by one...
NHibernate is simply not meant to do batch operations...

Comment: @MikedeKlerk I've updated the beginning of my answer with another example and some explanation why you don't need any counter if you use session.Delete...